# Observing changes to an object w/ KVO, context pointer doesn't seem to be working with a void*, but works with an NSString*

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, void-pointers

So I have a **MainController**,
inside of the header I have this `void*` declared:

```
static void *kStrokeColorWellChangedContext = &kStrokeColorWellChangedContext;
```

Inside of the implementation I am handling observation:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void*)context
{
   if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"color"] )
   {
      if( context == kStrokeColorWellChangedContext )
      {
         [self setValue:[change objectForKey:@"new"] forKey:@"strokeColor"];
      }
   }
```

Then I have a **ViewController** which has this line, which adds the **MainController** as an observer to a view

```
[self.strokeColorWell addObserver:self.toolController forKeyPath:@"color" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kStrokeColorWellChangedContext];
```

So when the view's color changes, it notifies the **MainController**, and enters the `-observeValueForKey:` routine, w/ the key `@"color"`

But it fails to enter into the inner `if` block, where I am checking `context`.

If I were to swap out my `void*` with an `NSString*` instead, it works as I would expect.

How could it be possible that the `void*` appears to have two different addresses stored into it?

**EDIT:**
Maybe the values of the `void*` could help

the result of `po kStrokeColorWellChangedContext`:

> 0x00000001005553e8

the result of `po context` in `-observeValueForKey:`:

> 0x0000000100555ea0
>
> objc[17775]: Method cache corrupted. This may be a message to an 
>   invalid object, or a memory error somewhere else.
>   objc[17775]: receiver 0x100555ea0, SEL 0x7fff899c8246, isa 0x100555ea0, cache  > 0x100555eb0, buckets 0x100566160, mask 0x0, occupied 0x0
>   objc[17775]: receiver 0 bytes, buckets 0 bytes
>   objc[17775]: selector 'respondsToSelector:'

The exceptions being thrown there may be a hint, but I really don't understand any of it

**EDIT2:**
The output of `p` instead of `po`

```
(lldb) p context
(void *) $5 = 0x0000000100555ea0
(lldb) p kStrokeColorWellChangedContext
(void *) $6 = 0x00000001005553e8
```

Please note that I am pretty-very confident that I am debugging the correct notification.
Two reasons why; the `keyPath` is unique and I see that value is correct.  Also if I use an `NSString*` as the context it works

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your `static void` line. Both sides of the `=` reference the same variable name. That is probably not what you mean to do.

Comment: I know it looks weird, but that seems to be The Way, as espoused on NSHipster - although the addObserver code is not shown in that case, but with or without & it should be the same

Comment: You can't use `po` with the `context` argument because `context` is not an object. That's why you're seeing an error message saying "This may be a message to an invalid object..."

Comment: Yep that's my mistake, I always thought `po` stood for "print out" haha.  Thanks for the correction, I have edited the question with the change

Comment: You should be comparing the *value* of `context`, i.e., `*context` -- in other words, you're comparing the addresses of two different variables, which willl never be the same. Instead, compare the value *at* the address of `context`.

Comment: Honestly though, wouldn't comparing to a string value be more straightforward, and help avoid this sort of confusion?

Comment: I don't know, honestly.  I just wanted to use this `void*` because it seemed in theory it would always be unique, and also because that's what I see in examples and resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` as a `static` variable in a header. Each translation unit (source file, basically) that imports that header will create a **separate** variable by that name, because it's declared `static` and that's what that means for variables at file scope.

So, each variable will have a separate address and, since the variable's value is its own address, each will have a different value.

You could declare the variable in the header and define it in an implementation such that there's only one such variable. The declaration in the header would look like:

```
extern void * const kStrokeColorWellChangedContext;
```

The definition in one of the implementation files would look like:

```
void * const kStrokeColorWellChangedContext = (void*)&kStrokeColorWellChangedContext;
```

Note that I've made the variable a `const` pointer to void. That disallows anything from assigning a new value to it, since it's supposed to be a constant.

Comment: This is the correct answer - I missed the "header" part. Nice one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for breaking it down and explaining it-- including the `const` keyword.  One quick question, if you have time: So you mention that every translation unit that imports the header will create a separate variable.  But I remember reading that `#import` " ensures that a file is only ever included once."  So do you know how that works, if I am always using `#import`?

Comment: Each translation unit imported your header. It only imports it once, as you say. So, each translation unit had the definition `static void *kStrokeColorWellChangedContext = ...` at file scope. Therefore, each translation unit had its own `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` variable, independent of the same-named variable in any other translation unit that also imported that same header. There's no need for the header to be imported *multiple times **for a given translation unit*** for that to cause problems.

Comment: Got it.  Makes 100% sense.  Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` "has" two addresses: its position in memory and its value and they're both the same! So `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` and `& kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` should be interchangeable throughout your program.

Have you tried stepping through your KVO callback and looking at/logging the values of `context` and `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext`? And `keyPath`?

Comment: The extent of my testing was to check the value of `context` passed into `-observeValue`.  Then in `lldb`, I typed `po kStrokeColorWellChangedContext`.  The two values were not the same, and I can confirm that the view is sending the notification to the MainController because if I swap the context I pass into `-addObserver` with a string, I can see the value of `context` is the string

Comment: No other observers are being added?

Comment: Yes actually-- I have the exact same setup with another view, with everything being the same except the context is named kFillColorWellChangedContext.  But this context value is also not the same as the `context` passed into `observeValue`

Also I could delete it, and the same issue is still there.  Very confusing, because we are using this pattern elsewhere in the workspace and it works just fine

Comment: I'd try deleting the other observer. I'd also check the view is the one you're expecting

Comment: No go :\  and made sure the view is the one i'm expecting. edited the question to include the results of the debugging

Comment: How about 'p' instead of 'po'? 'void*' isn't an object. You can also just look at the debug values in Xcode

Comment: Good call, I did that and the exceptions disappeared.  But the output is the same.  And I think it's interesting the values are the exact same as the last time I ran the application.  I would not have guessed.  I'm starting to lean more towards maybe the static void* cannot be public

Comment: Have you seen Ken Thomases answer? He noticed that you defined `kStrokeColorWellChangedContext` as `static` in a header, so you've got multiple versions floating around. Wish I'd noticed that.

Comment: Yup just saw it :)  Not a problem, thanks for your time, honestly appreciate it!

Comment: I wonder why NSString worked? Some linker string coalescing magic.

Comment: Oh that's simple, it's because it was just doing an `isEqual` comparison.  So when I added the observer w/ `-addObserver:blah:blah:context:`, I passed in something like `@"BlahBlahBlah"` as the `context`.  Then in `-observeValueForKey:blah:blah:context`, I checked to see if the `context` argument was equal to `@"BlahBlahBlah"` :)